# Abstract class in Java 5 or previous

Tags: java, class, methods, abstract, java-5

I've read in a book ( *Programmez en Java 5 et 6* by Claude Delannoy, in French) that in Java 5 and its previous versions, if you have an abstract method in a class then this class is abstract and it's not necessary to mention the keyword `abstract` before the class.

Is this statement true? I tried to find the Java SE 5 specification but it's unreachable.

Comment: In which book did you read this?

Comment: "Programmez en Java 5 et 6 - Claude Delannoy" it's in french

Comment: Clarify your questions by editing them, rather than adding comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle publishes the JLS going back to Java 6: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/ I'm not sure that JLS for Java 5 is available online.

That said, you're question has [the same answer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.1) regardless of which Java version is considered:

> Normal classes may have abstract methods ([§8.4.3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.1), [§9.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4)), that is,
>   methods that are declared but not yet implemented, only if they are
>   abstract classes.

This means: a class that has an abstract method must be declared abstract otherwise you'll get a compilation error.

Comment: thank you, but i've read this answer, but i'm still looking for java se5 spec.

Comment: @AbdelilahAassou I'm pretty sure that all versions <=5 have the same definition. See the [archived version of the first Java edition](http://web.archive.org/web/20041205073404/http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/first_edition/html/8.doc.html#34944).

Answer (score 7):

If you want to make a class [abstract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html),you need to declare it `abstract` no matter which version of java you are using.

If a class contains an abstract method,then that class also becomes abstract and you need to declare that class abstract to resolve compile issue.

Comment: Are you sure about versions <= 5 ?

Comment: Regardless, it would be bad practice to not declare it.